# php passing object of an object: reference or value?

Tags: php, zend-framework, object, reference

Hi all I'm using zend framework (but I think this is irrelevant) and php5 and I just want to modify an object of an object

```
  public function saveSite($post) {
    $form = new Diff_Form_Download();
    $subform = new Diff_Form_DownloadSubform();
    $form = $this->view->form;
    $newSite = 0;
    $sitesRecord = new Diff_Model_Sites();
    $debugString = null;

    if (is_array($post)) {
        $subform = $this->getSubformByPost($post);
        $debugString = $subform->getContent();
        echo $debugString;

        //new site instertion
        if (is_null($subform)) {
            $subform = $form->getSubForm('NewSite');
            $newSite = 1;
        }

        $values = reset($subform->getValues());

       $sitesRecord = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Diff_Model_Sites')->findOneBy('idSite', $values['idSite']);
        if ($sitesRecord) {
            $sitesRecord->idSite = $values['idSite']; //useless but necessary to make Doctrine understand to use update?
        } else { //if the record is not present instantiate a new object (otherwise save() will not work
            $sitesRecord = new Diff_Model_Sites();
        }

        $sitesRecord->content = $subform->getContent(); //$values['content'];
        $sitesRecord->newHtml = $subform->getContent();
        $sitesRecord->url = $values['url'];
        $sitesRecord->shortName = $values['shortName'];
        $sitesRecord->lastChanged = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $sitesRecord->pollingHours = $values['pollingHours'];
        $sitesRecord->minLengthChange = $values['minLenghtChange'];

        if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) { //save the owner
            $sitesRecord->idOwner = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->idOwner; //retrieve the owner
            $sitesRecord->save();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("your session have expired: \n please login again");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * return the calling subform
 * @param type $post
 * @return type 
 */
public function getSubformByPost($post) {
    $form = new Diff_Form_Download();
    $form = $this->view->form;
    $subform = new Diff_Form_DownloadSubform();
    $subformName = "site" . $post['idSite'];
    $subform = $form->getSubForm($subformName);

    return $subform;
}

public function refreshOneDiff($post) {
     $debugString;
    if (is_array($post)) {
        $form = new Diff_Form_Download();
        $form = $this->view->form;

        $subform = new Diff_Form_DownloadSubform();
        $subform = $this->getSubformByPost($post);

        if (!$subform)
            $subform = $this->view->form->getSubformByPost('NewSite');
        $url = $subform->getUrl();
        $idSite = $subform->getIdSite();

        $crawler = new Crawler();
        $newpageContent = $crawler->get_web_page($url);
        $siteRecord = new Diff_Model_Sites();
        $siteRecord = $subform->getSiteRecord();
        if ($siteRecord) //check if the record is not null
            $oldpageContent = $siteRecord->get('content');
        else
            $oldpageContent = null;

        $differences = $this->getDiff($oldpageContent, $newpageContent);

        if (!is_null($differences)) {
            $siteRecord->content = $newpageContent;
            $subform->setContent($newpageContent);
            $subform->setContentDiff($differences);
            $subform->setSiteRecord($siteRecord);
            $subform = $this->getSubformByPost($post);
            $debugString = $subform->getContent();
        }

            //echo $debugString;

        $sitePresence = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Diff_Model_Sites')->findOneBy('idSite', $idSite);
        if ($sitePresence) {
            //$this->saveSite($post);
            $this->debugtry($post);
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Basically what I'm doing here is:
1) grab a the form from the view
2) grab a subform from the form (let's call it SubformX)
3) grab an object "siteRecordX" from SubformX
4) change  a value of "siteRecordX"
5) call a function saveRecord()
6) In this function regrab the same SubformX and echoing the value of the object siteRecordX

Surprisingly if i change a variable of SubformX it will stay that way, if I change a variable of an object of SubformX it will remain unchanged (if I retrieve SubformX).
It looks like, even if SubformX is passed by reference it is not the same for it's subobjects, wich are passed by value and so they disappear changing the context of the function.
Can you please help me?
Thanks

EDIT
I still cannot solve this issue nor understand it:
This is the constructor of the subform:

```
    public function __construct($site = null, $options = null) {
    if ($site instanceof Diff_Model_Sites) {
        $this->_shortName = $site->get('shortName');
        $this->_url = $site->get('url');
        $this->_content = $site->get('content');
        $this->_idSite = $site->get('idSite');
        $this->_siteRecord = $site;
        $this->_lastChanged = $site->get('lastChanged');
    }parent::__construct($options);}
```

while this is the function of SubformX i use to set the value.

```
public function setContent($contentText) {
    $this->_siteRecord->content = $contentText;
    $this->_content = $contentText;
}
```

and this is the function of the subform that I call to get the value

```
    public function getContent() {
    if (isset($this->_siteRecord)) {
        //return $this->_content;
        return $this->_siteRecord->content;
    }
}
```

with the commented line I'm able to retrieve the updated value, not with the second.
This is a real mystery to me because i set and get them exactly the same way at exactly the same point and i cannot understand the difference.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php - although I'll admit that the information there may just cloud the issue further. The long of the short of it is that *all* objects are effectively always passed by reference regardless of context because you're not actually passing the object around, but a pointer to it. This means that even if you create a copy of the pointer, it still points to the same thing. The only way to create a copy of an object (in PHP5) is with `clone`. If the object appears unmodified later in the code, it's because you didn't modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have found that every indexAction calls again the constructor of each subform, which reloading the subform retrieve the element from the db before it is saved. I still have to figure it out how to change this behaviour. Any help can be appreciated. Where shoud i instantiate the objects, loading their value from the db? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_siteRecord` property is an ORM object (Doctrine, it appears).  So its data may have some behaviors that are not standard for a reference-type object.  It surely has some override of `__get` and `__set`.  It also employs caching.  These things are necessary to keep the database-model interaction working properly, but they can confuse what should be a reference and value types.  (See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html)

P.S.: in your constructor you use:

```
$this->_content = $site->get('content');
$this->_siteRecord = $site;
```

but in your getContent() you use:

```
$this->_siteRecord->content;
```

That difference might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys. It was Doctrine caching.
I have not investigated further the problem, but after getting rid of Doctrine everything works fine.
I have lost one entire day after this issue.
Moreover today I have lost another day for another curious problem related to Doctrine.
It seems that each time you gather data from your db Doctrine decode them for you (just like the php function utf8_decode($data).
Of course if you get the data and then put it back in the db again it will result in a total mayhem of coding and decoding.
This is enough. I still think that ORM are great programming tools but simply Doctrine is not.
I will not rest in peace since I'll have it eliminated from my program.
I will use Zend_Db library instead. Which I have mostly already done without regret and without facing the above-mentioned Doctrine's problems.
Again thanks to Seth Battin and Dave Random for the help and patience to understand my noob-coding.